# problem with login with facebook. suddenly not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Login with facebook suddenly stopped working on my website https://lendenadda.com . It was working swiftly before.Now its giving error with the following message.
I am using facebook graph version : 2.6

"Graph returned an error: Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I have tried changing the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs and I have tried response from the following urls

[Login with facebook suddenly stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801393/login-with-facebook-suddenly-stopped-working)

[Facebook login is suddenly not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234783/facebook-login-is-suddenly-not-working-anymore)

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '00000',
  'app_secret' => '00000',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  "persistent_data_handler"=>"session"
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state']; /*Add This*/
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```